# What topics can I ask about here?

Tags: discussion

I was wondering what questions are on-topic here, so I went to the ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) help page.  However, that page is extremely sparse.  It says only:

> What topics can I ask about here?
>
> Please look around to see if your question has been asked before. It’s also OK to ask and answer your own question.
>
> If your question is not specifically on-topic for elementary OS Stack Exchange, it may be on topic for another Stack Exchange site. If no site currently exists that will accept your question, you may commit to or propose a new site at Area51, the place where new Stack Exchange communities are democratically created.

Alright then.  That didn't really help, did it?

Would it be possible to add an explanation of what is on-topic here?

---

Here's what the tour says:

> elementary OS Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for developers and users of elementary OS and applications. [...]

As some feedback, when I read that, I initially assumed this meant that this site is for elementary-level questions about operating systems and applications.  Only after poking around a bit did I realize that "elementary OS" is referring to a particular product, and "elementary" is not an adjective modifying OS.  This would have been a lot clearer if the help page had contained anything useful.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for pointing this out to us. I'll talk to some other members of the site and we will get this sorted in the near future.

Comment: Ping? This is not great for a site with a pretty clear topic...

Comment: I did bring it up with the others but nothing happened as yet. My apologies. I'll look into it again.